# Solving $XX^T=A$ for complex $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

Let $A$ be a complex $n\times n$ matrix. When does $XX^T = A$ have a solution?

---

**My attempt:**

Since $(XX^T)^T=XX^T$, $A$ has to be a symmetric matrix to have a solution.

After googling, I got to know about [Cholesky Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition). According to this, if $A$ is real, then we can apply the decomposition for real matrices, and we have a solution.

Then, what about a complex case? I think Cholesky decomposition for complex matrices does not apply here because we have a transpose ($A^T$) instead of a conjugate transpose($A^*$).

Comment: It is solvable if and only if $A$ is complex symmetric, because every symmetric bilinear form over a field of characteristic $\ne2$ is diagonalisable by congruence.

Comment: @user1551 I know nothing about bilinear form, but how is it relevant here? Are we thinking about something like $f(a,b) = aXX^T b^T$? Also, what do you mean by "diagnosable by congruence"?

Comment: It means every symmetric matrix $A$ can be decomposed as a product of the form $P^TDP$, where $P$ is invertible and $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Now take $X=P^T\sqrt{D}$ where $\sqrt{D}$ is the entrywise square root of $D$.

Comment: @user1551 Oh okay, that completely answered the question. I would accept it if you would like to turn it into an answer.